# Why is my JS-program behaving differently with/without a 'problem line'?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, html5-canvas, getimagedata

The problem line is in the `handleLineEnd` function.
I ripped off all the lines not necessary to show the problem.

Without the line: I can draw multiple rectangles on the ctx.

With the line: Each rectangle is overwritten by the next rectangle.

The code runs fine in older Chrome (118.0.5993.71) vs not working in  version 119.0.6045.106

```
function handleLineEnd(evt) {
  {
    startDrawing = false;
    var dummy = ctx.getImageData(3, 3, 5, 5); // problem line
    ctx.drawImage(canvaslayer, 0, 0);
    ctxlayer.clearRect(0, 0, el.width, el.height);
  }
}
```

```js
var el = document.getElementById("canvasID");
var elcontainer = document.getElementById("containerID");
var ctx = el.getContext('2d');
var startpuntX, startpuntY, eindpuntX, eindpuntY;
var startDrawing = false;
var container = el.parentNode; // Add the temporary canvas.
var containerHandletje = document.getElementById('containerID');
var ongoingTouches = new Array();
var huidigeKleur = 'black';
var huidigeDikte = 2;
var selectie = document.getElementById('drawingtoolID');
elcontainer.setAttribute("style", 'width: ' + (window.innerWidth - 12) + 'px; height: ' + (window.innerHeight - 80) + 'px; overflow: auto;');
el.height = window.innerHeight - 90;
el.width = window.innerWidth - 42;
canvaslayer = document.createElement('canvas');
canvaslayer.id = 'imageTemp';
canvaslayer.width = el.width;
canvaslayer.height = el.height;
canvaslayer.style = 'touch-action:none;';
container.appendChild(canvaslayer);
ctxlayer = canvaslayer.getContext('2d');
ctxlayer.lineCap = 'round';
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
ctx.lineCap = 'round';
ctx.fillStyle = 'white'
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, el.width, el.height);
ctx.lineWidth = huidigeDikte;
canvaslayer.addEventListener('pointerdown', handleLineStart, false);
canvaslayer.addEventListener('pointerup', handleLineEnd, false);
canvaslayer.addEventListener('pointermove', handleLineMove, false);

function handleLineStart(evt) {
  startpuntX = evt.clientX - el.offsetLeft + pageXOffset + containerHandletje.scrollLeft;
  startpuntY = evt.clientY - container.offsetTop + pageYOffset + containerHandletje.scrollTop;
  ctxlayer.lineWidth = huidigeDikte;
  ctxlayer.strokeStyle = huidigeKleur;
  ctxlayer.fillStyle = huidigeKleur;
  startDrawing = true;
  ctxlayer.stroke();
  ctxlayer.beginPath();
  handleLineMove(evt);
}

function handleLineMove(evt) {
  var x, y, w, h, hokDx, xi, yi, asX, asY, asXeind, asYeind, fontsize, dzx, dzy, situatie;
  if (startDrawing) {
    eindpuntX = evt.clientX - el.offsetLeft + pageXOffset + containerHandletje.scrollLeft;
    eindpuntY = evt.clientY - container.offsetTop + pageYOffset + containerHandletje.scrollTop;
    ctxlayer.clearRect(0, 0, el.width, el.height);
    ctxlayer.beginPath();
    ctxlayer.moveTo(startpuntX, startpuntY);
    x = Math.min(startpuntX, eindpuntX);
    y = Math.min(startpuntY, eindpuntY);
    w = Math.abs(startpuntX - eindpuntX);
    h = Math.abs(startpuntY - eindpuntY);
    ctxlayer.strokeRect(x, y, w, h);
    ctxlayer.stroke();
    ctxlayer.beginPath();
  }
}

function handleLineEnd(evt) {
  {
    startDrawing = false;
    var dummy = ctx.getImageData(3, 3, 5, 5); // problem line
    ctx.drawImage(canvaslayer, 0, 0);
    ctxlayer.clearRect(0, 0, el.width, el.height);
  }
}
```

```css
#containerID {
  position: relative;
}

#canvasID {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#imageTemp {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div id="containerID" style="touch-action:none; width: 100px; height: 500px; overflow: auto;">
  <canvas id='canvasID' width='80' height='80' style='margin-left:10px;background:white;border:solid black 1px; touch-action:none; '>
    Your browser does not support canvas element.
  </canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me in the snippet both with and without the 2 extraneous lines.

Comment: The code appears to work fine, but there is a difference in behaviour, with the 2 lines commented out, multiple rectangles can be drawn

Comment: @JamesThorpe I'm able to draw multiple rectangles both with and without those two lines. They change nothing about the drawing logic.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Interesting - for me I get the same behaviour OP is reporting, each rectangle disappears when the next is drawn with the original code.  I agree that those lines shouldn't change anything though!

Comment: Strange. I've tested with latest Chrome and Firefox on Windows.

Comment: I'm on previous version of chrome and whatever version of Edge is currently installed, on windows - both do what OP claimed.  Just fired up Firefox, and it agrees with you! Very odd...

Comment: It is running fine in firefox, but not in Chrome. Why?

Comment: @mplungjan they're at the bottom, both commented `// problem line`

Comment: I just relaunched chrome to update, it's still behaving as described with a difference in behaviour with those lines removed.  Version 119.0.6045.160.

Comment: Why would you have two identical lines in the script in the first place? `var dummy = ctx.getImageData(3, 3, 5, 5); var dummy = ctx.getImageData(3, 3, 5, 5);`

Comment: @James Thorpe: thank you for you efforts. It's fine to hear it is not just me.

Comment: Works in Chrome 118.0.5993.71  - I just updated now to 119.0.6045.106 and I see the issue - I only need one of the lines to show this (makes sense) and the problem goes away when I comment the line out

Comment: I have edited your question and voted to re-open. There is no reason to have two identical lines with the second overwriting the first.

Comment: I also see a console message: `multiple readback operations using getImageData are faster with the willReadFrequently attribute set to true. See: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#concept-canvas-will-read-frequently`

Comment: You have found a new (or could be known) Chrome 2D API bug as the behaviour is not correct. `getImageData` should not affect subsequent render calls. I could reproduce bug on Chrome V119.0.6045.160 (64-bit) Win11. Note when I moved the last 3 lines of `handleLineEnd` to bottom of `handleLineMove` the bug disappeared if one dragged a box for about a second. BTW you don't need any of the calls `ctxlayer.stroke(`, `ctxlayer,.beginPath(`, or `ctxlayer.moveTo(` they do nothing (Nor do they affect the bug)

Answer (score 5):

This is a known and fixed Chrome bug ([CRBUG 1500272](https://crbug.com/1500272) and [CRBUG 1499539](https://crbug.com/1499539)) that was caused by [this CL](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/63cc88a00dfe15f406487da666eb5c2611120963). Basically they're rewriting their canvas layer logic and this messed up with when these get flushed. Roughly, calling `getImageData()` does move the layer around from the GPU to the CPU and that change made the bridge not handle that moving correctly, leaving the GPU side without a resource provider.

Note that we can reduce the bug repro down to:

```js
const el = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = el.getContext('2d');
const canvaslayer = document.createElement('canvas');
const ctxlayer = canvaslayer.getContext('2d');

const draw = (pos) => {
  ctxlayer.fillRect(pos, pos, 30, 30);
  ctx.getImageData(3, 3, 5, 5); // problem line
  ctx.drawImage(canvaslayer, 0, 0);
  ctxlayer.clearRect(0, 0, el.width, el.height);
};

draw(30);
// We need to wait at least  after the next painting frame
// But 1s makes it clearer somethign is wrong.
setTimeout(() => draw(60), 1000);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Of possible workarounds:

Do not use an accelerated canvas. By requesting your 2D context with the `willReadFrequently` option, you'll avoid your canvas is moved around. If you are going to do many readbacks on your canvas, you may really want to consider this option, even without the bug. Moving the canvas around is very slow and the little you may have won through hardware acceleration (which might not even be much depending on what you draw), will be lost in these calls.

```js
const el = document.querySelector("canvas");
// Since we're going to do read-backs on this context
// let's deaccelerate it.
const ctx = el.getContext('2d', { willReadFrequently: true });
const canvaslayer = document.createElement('canvas');
const ctxlayer = canvaslayer.getContext('2d');

const draw = (pos) => {
  ctxlayer.fillRect(pos, pos, 30, 30);
  ctx.getImageData(3, 3, 5, 5); // problem line
  ctx.drawImage(canvaslayer, 0, 0);
  ctxlayer.clearRect(0, 0, el.width, el.height);
};

draw(30);
setTimeout(() => draw(60), 1000);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

If you really think you must use an accelerated canvas, then you could use an `OffscreenCanvas` instead of the `canvaslayer` `<canvas>` element. `OffscreenCanvas` aren't causing that bug (for whatever reasons...).

```js
const el = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = el.getContext('2d');
const canvaslayer = new OffscreenCanvas(300, 300);
const ctxlayer = canvaslayer.getContext('2d');

let pos = false;
const draw = (pos) => {
  ctxlayer.fillRect(pos, pos, 30, 30);
  ctx.getImageData(3, 3, 5, 5); // problem line
  ctx.drawImage(canvaslayer, 0, 0);
  ctxlayer.clearRect(0, 0, el.width, el.height);
};

draw(30);
setTimeout(() => draw(60), 1000);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

From your code though, since you need the `layercanvas` to be visible, you'd use `layercanvas.transferControlToOffscreen()` instead of the constructor, so that the `<canvas>` element becomes a placeholder canvas and still paints its content to screen.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("canvasID");
var elcontainer = document.getElementById("containerID");
var ctx = el.getContext('2d');
var startpuntX, startpuntY, eindpuntX, eindpuntY;
var startDrawing = false;
var container = el.parentNode; // Add the temporary canvas.
var containerHandletje = document.getElementById('containerID');
var ongoingTouches = new Array();
var huidigeKleur = 'black';
var huidigeDikte = 2;
var selectie = document.getElementById('drawingtoolID');
elcontainer.setAttribute("style", 'width: ' + (window.innerWidth - 12) + 'px; height: ' + (window.innerHeight - 80) + 'px; overflow: auto;');
el.height = window.innerHeight - 90;
el.width = window.innerWidth - 42;
const canvaslayerEl = document.createElement('canvas');
canvaslayerEl.id = 'imageTemp';
canvaslayerEl.width = el.width;
canvaslayerEl.height = el.height;
canvaslayerEl.style = 'touch-action:none;';
container.appendChild(canvaslayerEl);
// Use an OffscreenCanvas to avoid Chrome bug 1500272
const canvaslayer = canvaslayerEl.transferControlToOffscreen();
const ctxlayer = canvaslayer.getContext('2d');
ctxlayer.lineCap = 'round';
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
ctx.lineCap = 'round';
ctx.fillStyle = 'white'
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, el.width, el.height);
ctx.lineWidth = huidigeDikte;
canvaslayerEl.addEventListener('pointerdown', handleLineStart, false);
canvaslayerEl.addEventListener('pointerup', handleLineEnd, false);
canvaslayerEl.addEventListener('pointermove', handleLineMove, false);

function handleLineStart(evt) {
  startpuntX = evt.clientX - el.offsetLeft + pageXOffset + containerHandletje.scrollLeft;
  startpuntY = evt.clientY - container.offsetTop + pageYOffset + containerHandletje.scrollTop;
  ctxlayer.lineWidth = huidigeDikte;
  ctxlayer.strokeStyle = huidigeKleur;
  ctxlayer.fillStyle = huidigeKleur;
  startDrawing = true;
  ctxlayer.stroke();
  ctxlayer.beginPath();
  handleLineMove(evt);
}

function handleLineMove(evt) {
  var x, y, w, h, hokDx, xi, yi, asX, asY, asXeind, asYeind, fontsize, dzx, dzy, situatie;
  if (startDrawing) {
    eindpuntX = evt.clientX - el.offsetLeft + pageXOffset + containerHandletje.scrollLeft;
    eindpuntY = evt.clientY - container.offsetTop + pageYOffset + containerHandletje.scrollTop;
    ctxlayer.clearRect(0, 0, el.width, el.height);
    ctxlayer.beginPath();
    ctxlayer.moveTo(startpuntX, startpuntY);
    x = Math.min(startpuntX, eindpuntX);
    y = Math.min(startpuntY, eindpuntY);
    w = Math.abs(startpuntX - eindpuntX);
    h = Math.abs(startpuntY - eindpuntY);
    ctxlayer.strokeRect(x, y, w, h);
    ctxlayer.stroke();
    ctxlayer.beginPath();
  }
}

function handleLineEnd(evt) {
  {
    startDrawing = false;
    var dummy = ctx.getImageData(3, 3, 5, 5); // problem line
    ctx.drawImage(canvaslayer, 0, 0);
    ctxlayer.clearRect(0, 0, el.width, el.height);
  }
}
```

```css
#containerID {
  position: relative;
}

#canvasID {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#imageTemp {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div id="containerID" style="touch-action:none; width: 100px; height: 500px; overflow: auto;">
  <canvas id='canvasID' width='80' height='80' style='margin-left:10px;background:white;border:solid black 1px; touch-action:none; '>
    Your browser does not support canvas element.
  </canvas>
</div>
```

But that's an ugly hack-around, for a bug that's already been fixed and which should disappear in the next Chrome release (current Chrome Beta has the fix already).

Comment: Great answer as always!

Comment: Thank you very much for all the work(arounds!). Really helped.

Answer (score -3):

There are libraries that will make all that and much more, and your code will look a lot simpler, for example http://fabricjs.com/ that will allow you to add shapes and give the user control of location, rotation and dimensions, you can also group shapes or make it not selectable.

Look at my sample below, I added 3 rectangles to a group and added an event listener, double click will add a new rectangle that user can modify later.

[image]

```js
canvas = new fabric.Canvas("a")

objs = []
objs.push(new fabric.Rect({left: 50, top: 50, height: 50, width: 50, fill: "red" }))
objs.push(new fabric.Rect({left: 90, top: 60, height: 50, width: 50, fill: "green"}))
objs.push(new fabric.Rect({left: 70, top: 80, height: 50, width: 50, fill: "blue" }))

group = new fabric.Group(objs, { left: 30, top: 0, opacity: 0.8, selectable: false })
canvas.add(group)

canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({left: 400, top: 40, height: 20, width: 80 }))
canvas.renderAll()

canvas.on('mouse:dblclick', (evt) => {
    rect = new fabric.Rect({
      left: evt.pointer.x, 
      top: evt.pointer.y, 
      height: 40, 
      width: 40, 
      stroke: "black", 
      fill: "" 
    })
    canvas.add(rect)
    canvas.setActiveObject(rect);
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/5.3.1/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="a" width="600" height="160"></canvas>
```